# NSPredicate to Search Collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a tableview with a search bar.  I was able to use NSPredicate to search the tableview when I add the items to another array:

```
for(head in items){
   [desc addObject:head.DESC];
   [category addObject:head.CATEGORY];
 }

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
   NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [desc filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Now I want to keep the collection together so that a tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath will be able to use the category object.

I load my table view like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++){
    head = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    labelName.text = head.DESC;
```

How can I get my NSPredicate to search the collection for head.DESC?

```
 #pragma mark Search Results
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
  {
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Currently, I am getting this exception when running the above code.

```
reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <Order: 0x7b22e900> (not a collection)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question. You want to be able to filter your `items` array (which is a bunch of `head`s) by the `DESC` property. How about using blocks?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
      return [[evaluatedObject DESC] containsString:searchText];
    }];

  searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

If your `Order` object defines `DESC` as a `@property` (or is otherwise KVC Compliant), you'll be able to just access it directly. This should work:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.DESC CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
  searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, I don't have a great understanding of blocks.  This control reaches end of non-void block.  What do I need to return?

Comment: Ha! Whoops! There should be a return at the beginning of that line. That's my fault.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't crash.  The search results are empty.  Is there a way with out blocks?

Comment: I'm not sure. I find blocks to be the best way for me to express things. Are you sure that your `items[i].DESC`s contain the `searchText` you tried?

Comment: Yes, the tableview is populated, and I tried searching an item on the tableview.

Comment: You could add in some `NSLog`s to the block if you're curious about the suspicious results. `NSLog(@"s(%@) in d(%@) ? %d", searchText, [evaluatedObject DESC], ([[evaluatedObject DESC] containsString:searchText]));`

Comment: 2014-10-28 11:17:14.843 Toolbox[67388:5749959] s(z) in d(ZINGER 64OZ) ? 0

Comment: Looks like you're expecting a case-insensitive search. You could update it to use `[[[evaluatedObject DESC] lowercaseString] containsString:[searchText lowercaseString]]` if case isn't important to you.

Comment: my original had predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@".  Is there a way to do contains or begins with in a block?

Comment: I think i have it figured out.  Thank you for the information and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.DESC CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
  searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Comment: it would have to be @"self.DESC CONTAINS[cd] %@" NSMutableArray not an NSArray.  Thanks though!